# "Hello@Domain.com" Email Addresses

Tags: email, contact-us

I've noticed an increasing trend among companies (especially smaller companies and agencies) to have a "hello@domain.com" email address as the initial point of contact. My understanding of this is that it helps to promote a friendly, human side to the address.

My question is - has there been any research done to back this up? Has anyone shown that this makes people more comfortable (and therefore more likely to get in touch), or is it simply another fad?

Comment: Probably better than the one my company used on its website: "marketing@domain.com". Sheesh, if there was ever an email address you *wouldn't* want to get in contact with it'd be the marketing department.

Comment: On that RFC http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2142.txt there are Standard email for domain but nowadays I don't think many people (even the domain admin) know the existence of them.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The hello@domain.com address simply implies that when someone is going to send an email to that address, there will likely be a human on the other end. It's a subtle and friendly way to market yourself as a personable company with a personality.

I automatically think of Aaron Walter over at Mailchimp and his approach to designing for emotions. Little things such as the "hello" domain name usually evoke positive responses in users

http://uxdesign.smashingmagazine.com/2012/07/18/the-personality-layer/